# I can't improve my boot time further

Tags: boot

I already spent a lot of time to improve my boot time and now I reached a bound I can't surpass.

So, I thought about asking here to look for help.

systemd's commands output:

1) systemd-analyze

```
systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 4.362s (kernel) + 28.046s (userspace) = 32.408s
graphical.target reached after 28.032s in userspace
```

2) systemd-analyze blame

```
systemd-analyze blame
         19.562s dev-sda2.device
         17.507s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
         16.429s systemd-sysctl.service
          3.079s networkd-dispatcher.service
          2.990s NetworkManager.service
          1.874s accounts-daemon.service
          1.641s udisks2.service
          1.540s grub-common.service
          1.145s preload.service
          1.134s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.057s keyboard-setup.service
           605ms systemd-journald.service
           537ms ufw.service
           429ms swapfile.swap
           421ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B07A\x2d539E.service
           415ms apparmor.service
           402ms systemd-random-seed.service
           396ms systemd-logind.service
           338ms setvtrgb.service
           317ms plymouth-read-write.service
           316ms binfmt-support.service
           313ms upower.service
           306ms systemd-remount-fs.service
```

3) systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @28.032s
└─multi-user.target @28.030s
  └─getty.target @28.028s
    └─getty@tty1.service @28.027s
      └─system-getty.slice @28.024s
        └─setvtrgb.service @27.684s +338ms
          └─systemd-user-sessions.service @27.665s +13ms
            └─network.target @27.663s
              └─NetworkManager.service @24.671s +2.990s
                └─dbus.service @24.446s
                  └─basic.target @24.429s
                    └─paths.target @24.428s
                      └─acpid.path @24.426s
                        └─sysinit.target @24.377s
                          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @24.149s +226ms
                            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @23.859s +241ms
                              └─local-fs.target @23.847s
                                └─boot-efi.mount @23.651s +195ms
                                  └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B07A\x2d539E.service @23.197s +421ms
                                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B07A\x2d539E.device @23.172s
```

**FYI: I have an HDD.**

Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: My system's specs

```
System:    Host: federico-Aspire-E5-573G Kernel: 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: LXDE (Openbox 3.6.1) dm: lightdm
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Acer product: Aspire E5-573G v: V3.72 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Acer model: ZORO_BH v: Type2 - A01 Board Version serial: N/A
           UEFI: Insyde v: V1.07 date: 03/17/2015
Battery    BAT1: charge: 27.3 Wh 86.0% condition: 31.7/37.0 Wh (86%)
           volts: 16.2/14.8
           model: SANYO AL15A32 serial: <filter>status: Discharging
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4005U (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: Haswell rev.1 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 6784
           clock speeds: min/max: 800/1600 MHz 1: 798 MHz 2: 798 MHz
           3: 798 MHz 4: 798 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a16
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK208BM [GeForce 920M]
           bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1299
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile
           version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 04:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:0e0f
           Card-2 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:9c20
           Card-3 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a0c
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-66-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000
           bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath10k_pci bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 168c:0042
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (11.2% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST500LT012 size: 500.1GB
           serial: <filter> temp: 27C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 457G used: 53G (13%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 168 Uptime: 6 min Memory: 642.8/3865.5MB
           Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201 running in x-terminal-emul) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Steps already taken:

- Swapiness
- DEFAULT GRUB TIME
- Disabled most of useless services (not all of them, because I'm not totally sure about some).
- Quiet splash in grub removed
- Plymouth masked

Comment: sda2 is your bottleneck. so get an ssd.

Comment: Please make sure you back up your important data safely and frequently. In the quest to reduce boot-up time, you may follow advice that results in unintended consequences. It maybe helpful to post your system specs. If you install *inxi*, the output of `inxi -Fxxz` would tell people more about your machine.

Comment: You should also include, as part of the question and *not* as comments, what steps you've already taken. Doing so will ensure people don't suggest steps you've already taken.

Comment: @DKBose I did what you've asked for. Thank you very much for you time!

Comment: I too have a Dual core Intel Core i3 and my times are worse than yours. But since I boot up just once a day, I don't bother in case I break something. Sorry, that I can't help!